# Changing Flex application indentifier

Tags: apache-flex

How would I change the application identifer for a Flex app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some requirements regarding the application id.  From the docs:

> An identifier string unique to the application, known as the application ID. The attribute value is restricted to the following characters:
>
> - 0-9
> - a-z
> - A-Z
> - . (dot)
> - - (hyphen)
>
> The value must contain between 1 to 212 characters.

If your new value follows these requirements and you still get an error, post a specific question about the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks, I must have been adding spaces or something.